# nginx https www redirect to non-www using let's encrypt certbot

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

Hi this must be a basic question but I haven't seen an answer with cerbot considerations (if there are any considerations). How do I get https www to redirect to non-www instead of timing out?

The **https www** version of my site times out instead of redirecting to non-www, whereas all other versions (http and https non-www) work fine.

Preferably I would like to future proof so that I can renew the certs through certbot and not need to manually change the nginx config afterwards.

The nginx server config is shown below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate <path_to_cert> # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key <path_to_key>; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam <path_to_this>

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman, thanks for the comment, have updated with an explicit question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use separate server blocks for each of the four variations of http/s and www/non-www. You never use "if" statements if you can do things another way - [Nginx If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

```
# http server, static websites        
server {            
  server_name example.com;            

  listen 443 ssl http2;            

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;            
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;            

  root     /var/www/***rootdir;            
}            

# This server simply redirects the requested to the https version of the page            
server {            
  listen 80;            
  server_name www.example.com example.com;            

  # Let's Encrypt certificates with Acmetool            
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {            
    alias /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;            
  }            

  location / {            
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;            
  }            
}            

server {            
  listen 443 ssl http2;            
  server_name www.example.com;            

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;            
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;            

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;            
}
```

Comment: Apparently certbot's nginx plugin writes this strange configuration, which is one reason I run it in webroot mode and write the configs myself.

Comment: I couldn't get certbot going in Amazon Linux back when I was trying, so I use [Acme](https://github.com/hlandau/acme) instead.

Comment: Hi thanks @tim, it looks like Acme might be the best way to go. I've managed to get myself sorted using your config as a basis. I would accept your answer but you are going from non-www to www and not from www to non-www. Wouldn't want to confuse other viewers of the question.

Comment: I've edited the post so it shows redirection to non-www